# In python, how can I prevent the "^C" from showing up when I press Ctrl+C in the terminal?

Tags: python

I have a signal handler which does its job, but the only ugly thing is whenever Ctrl+C is pressed, a "^C" shows up in the terminal. How do I get rid of that? Or is that a shell behavior?

Comment: That's terminal behaviour, it has nothing to do with Python or the shell.

Comment: Why would you want to anyway? It tells the _user_ that Ctrl+C has been pressed…

Comment: @DonalFellows I think the user would know if he/she pressed Ctrl+C or not

Comment: You'd be surprised (unless you're cynical enough). You'd also be forgetting that people switch between terminals and want to keep a record of what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Unix platform, the easiest way to control the terminal is the `curses` module.  You can turn the echoing of typed characters off with [`curses.noecho()`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.noecho), turn it on again with [`curses.echo()`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.echo), or wrap a function call in [`curses.wrapper()`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) to turn echoing off during the function call.  The latter is the preferred approach -- it will automatically restore the terminal state if an exception occurs.